# Possible to use two classes in blade?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Wondering if it's possible to use two classes in blade, look at comment here. One of the class is linked to check if it's active and the other is for the icon.

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a class='home' {{HTML::linkRoute('hvertime','Forside')}} </a> </li>
          HERE // <li <a class='home' @if($aktiv == 'hvertredjetime'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('hvertredjetime','Måling')}} </a></li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'gjoremal'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('gjoremal','Daglige Oppgaver')}} </li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'dagvakt'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('dagvakt','Dagvakt')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'kveldsvakt'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('kveldsvakt','Kveldsvakt')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'kontrollcm'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('kontrollcm','Kontroll CM')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'sok'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('sok','Søk')}}</li>  
              {{--  <li @if($aktiv == 'diagrammer'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('diagrammer','Diagrammer')}}</li>  --}} 
              {{--  <li @if($aktiv == 'rapport'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('rapport','Rapport')}}</li>  --}} 

          </ul>
```

css.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:before,
.navbar-nav>li>a:before {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 top;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 29px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a.home:before,
.navbar-nav>li>a.home:before { background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/j2s9NKB.png'); }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a.home:before,
.navbar-nav>li>a.home:before { background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/j2s9NKB.png'); }
```

Comment: I am not aware of `blade`, but you can have multiple css classes for a html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use checks in blade within the double braces like this and add additional classes according to variable values.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a class='home'>{{ HTML::linkRoute('hvertime','Forside') }}</a>
    </li>
    <li class='{{ ($aktiv == 'hvertredjetime') ? 'active' : '' }}'>
      <a class='home'>{{HTML::linkRoute('hvertredjetime','Måling')}}</a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for the ternary operators.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. But I dont know why it looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mppxcckjjidx1fk/bilde1.png
Why text have jumped down.

Comment: hard to see the exact problem by a screenshot, seems more like a bootstrap problem. the laravel blade problem should be solved though. also i edited my code above to put the active class into the <li> tag.

Comment: That worked. I just dont understand why the text is under the icon :/ I will ask a new question about it. You solved my laravel question.